# Does iOS 4.2 SDK supports custom fonts?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I've been trying to use custom fonts on the XCode with 4.2 SDK, using this method:

http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/using-custom-fonts-in-your-ios-application/

Although technically I'm sure I did everything right, the simulator didn't display the font.

Makes me wonder whether this feature is still supported in the latest SDK, since all those tutorials use previous SDKs. Someone from the Titanium forum also complained about the same thing.

Anyone had success using custom fonts on 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: yes it does. Yes, I have. So maybe you did overlook something?

Where exactly are you trying to use your font? Have you tried `[UIFont fontWithName:@"bla"]` ? Or are you trying to specifically display it in HTML?

Comment: Yes...I used `seconds.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Radioland" size:90];` Hm maybe I should triple check whether I correctly edit the plist entry..thanks!

Comment: If the font is in a proper format (e.g. .ttf or .otf), you added the font in your .plist, added the asset to XCode, and the name of the font is "Radioland" (check with [UIFont familyNames] and [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName]), then that should indeed work.

Comment: Got it working finally, it seems in the plist file I have to put `UIAppFonts` not `Fonts provided by application` to get it working. Thank you so much for your help in pointing me to the right direction!